# How to limit the queryset of related fields of serializer based on some request parameters in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have three models `Transaction`, `Business`, and `Location`. They are defined as follows:

```
class Business(models.Model): 
    # Can have zero or more locations. A user can have many businesses.
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[MinLengthValidator(1)])
    # ... and some other fields ...

class Location(models.Model): 
    # Must have one business. Locations cannot exist without a business
    suburb   = models.CharField(max_length=150, validators=[MinLengthValidator(1)])
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name='locations')
    # ... and some other fields ...

class Transaction(models.Model): 
    # Can have zero or one business
    # Can have zero or one location and the location must belong to the business. If business is empty, location must be empty
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='transactions')
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='transactions')
    # ... and some other fields ...
```

And the serializers:

```
class BusinessRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def get_queryset(self):
        owner = get_owner_from_context(self.context)
        return Business.objects.filter(owner=owner)

class LocationRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def get_queryset(self):
        params = self.context['request'].query_params
        business_params = params.get('business')
        if business_params is not None:
            owner = get_owner_from_context(self.context)
            return Location.objects.filter(owner=owner, business=business_params)
        else:
            return None

class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    business = BusinessRelatedField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    location = LocationRelatedField(required=False, allow_null=True)
```

The problem I was facing was that I didn't know how to restrict the value of `Location` based on the value of `Business`. I was manually performing this check inside `TransactionSerializer`'s `validate` method until it occurred to me to create a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` subclass and override the `get_queryset` method. This seemed like a better approach to me (and it's actually working) but I'd like to know if this is the 'normal' way of doing it.

The other problem I'm now facing is that the 'browsable API' no longer shows any choices for `Location` which I feel is a hint that I might be doing something wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Slightly modified the question title. Please feel free to modify the edit or even revert the edit, if you feel so.

Comment: @TomChristie could you please advise on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can **override the `get_fields()` method of the serializer and modify the `queryset` for `business` and `location` fields** to the desired values.

`get_fields()` method is used by the serializer to generate the `field names -> field instances` mapping when `.fields` property is accessed on it.

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = (.., business, transaction)

    def get_fields(self):
        # get the original field names to field instances mapping
        fields = super(TransactionSerializer, self).get_fields()

        # get the required parameters
        owner = get_owner_from_context(self.context)
        business_params = self.context['request'].query_params.get('business')

        # modify the queryset
        fields['business'].queryset = Business.objects.filter(owner=owner)
        fields['location'].queryset = Location.objects.filter(owner=owner, business=business_params)

        # return the modified fields mapping
        return fields
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this approach has the same result as the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` subclasses. 
The Browsable API still doesn't update the `Location` choices based on the `Business` selection; and it makes sense because in both approaches (subclass and `get_fields` method) we're trying to read `business` from the `request`, but the Browsable API doesn't generate a request when the user selects a choice.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This method can be used when you already have the parameters beforehand in your url. When you hit browsable API, there will no parameters, so resulting queryset would be empty leading to no choices.

Comment: this helped me a lot. +1 for the clarity

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, however it would not be different back then.

With the information you provided (in the comments as well) and AFAIK there is no way of doing this unless you manipulate the javascript code of the browsable API's templates and add `ajax` calling methods to it.

[DRF browsable API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/) and [DRF HTML and forms](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/) may help.